# disaggregate raster value to finer cells equally

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a SpatRaster in the following dimension

```
  layer1

  class       : SpatRaster
  dimensions  : 3600, 3600, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
  resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
  extent      : -81.00014, -80.00014, 24.99986, 25.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
  source      : nn.tif
  name        : nn_1
```

I have another SpatRaster which has data for revenue (in dollar) at a different resolution than `layer1`

```
  layer2
  class       : SpatRaster
  dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
  resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
  extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
  source      : XX.nc
  varname     : XX
  name        : XX
  unit        : US dollar
```

What I want to do is to take the average of `layer1` using `layer2` as weights. This is my approach:

1. Give them the same projections.

   ```
   layer2 <- project(layer2, crs(layer1))
   ```
2. Clip `layer2` to match the extent of `layer1`

   ```
    r <- terra::crop(layer2, ext(layer1))
    r <- terra::mask(r, layer1) # I get error in this step
    [mask] number of rows and/or columns do not match
   ```
3. Suppose step 2 worked. Now I want to disaggregate clipped `layer2` to match the resolution of `layer1` i.e. 30 times finer.
   This means revenue of each disaggregated cell should be 1/30 of the revenue of the parent cell.
   Is the below the right way to do this:

   ```
    r_disagg <- disaggregate(r, fact = 30)/30
   ```
4. Divide each cell value in `r_disagg` with total sum of `r_disagg` to get a weight raster `r_disagg_wt`
5. Multiply `r_disagg_wt` with `layer1` and add the resulting raster to get the weighted average of `layer1`

I am stuck in step 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking an R question, please include example data like this

Example data

```
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(nrow=360, ncol=360, ext=c(-81.00014, -80.00014, 24.99986, 25.99986))
r2 <- rast(nrow=2160, ncol=4320)
values(r1) <- 1:ncell(r1)
set.seed(0)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
```

Solution

```
re2 <- resample(r2, r1)
global(r1, fun="mean", weights=re2)
#      weighted_mean
#lyr.1      66190.15
```

In cases where the two input rasters align, it could be preferable to use `disagg` instead of `resample` (in this case, the extent of `r1` is a bit odd, it seems to be shifted with half a cell).

There is no need to adjust the dollar values if they are only used as weights. In cases that the sum of the cell values should remain constant, when using `resample` or `project`, you could compute the density ($/km<sup>2</sup>) before resampling by dividing the values with the area of each cell (see `cellSize`) and multiply the values again with the area of the new cells after resampling.